# Reason for <time> element

Tags: html, time

Why is there a `<time>` element in HTML5? It seems to work similar to a `<p>` element, but I'm not sure I'm using it right, as it seems to only work when I use this code:

```
<body>
    <time>10:00</time>
</body>
```

Am I using this right? Why was it implemented in HTML? What is its purpose?

Comment: It is very difficult to know what you are talking about. Could you provide some example HTML to clarify what you mean?

Comment: It has semantic value where `<p>10:00</p>` doesn't (or not as much).

Comment: When in doubt look up the docs on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time)

Answer (score 1):

Like we have tags `<footer> <body> <aside>` its the same way `<time>`. So basically the time is wrapped with that tag